# Getting sObject name within JS Script in VF Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I want to get the sObject name in JS section of VF Page .
I have the object id .

```
 var objectID = [];
 objectID = Id;
```

Something akin to :

```
String sObjName = myId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

I understood you want to get this information with JS only. Then you'd have to use a Salesforce API or code the mapping for yourself.

If you can also use Apex, a Controller or Controller Extension will do the trick.